# Changing the value of variables in a class through a function outside the class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, global-variables

I am trying to modify the value of a variable (in this case an integer) that is located inside of a class using a function that's outside of that class. But when I call the function, the value of the variable `us_balance` stays the same: `42`.

```
class Country:
    us_balance = 42

def buy(country, amount):
    if country.lower == "us":
        Country.us_balance = Country.us_balance - amount

def stats():
    print(Country.us_balance)

while True:
    user_input = input("> ").lower()

    if user_input == "buy":
        amount = input("$ ").lower()
        balance_to_set = amount.split()
        buy(balance_to_set[0], int(balance_to_set[1]))
    if user_input == "stats":
        stats()
        break
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `lower` is a function; you need to call it: `if country.lower() == "us":`

Comment: wow I did not realize that! It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was just add parentheses to the .upper() function in the class

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of the class and pass that in to the various functions. By using `Country` it is creating a new instance of the class each time and that is why the stats function is reporting 42 as the value.

Here's a example that should work for you.

```
class Country:
    us_balance = 42

def buy(ci, country, amount):
    if country.lower() == "us":
        new = ci.us_balance = ci.us_balance - amount
        ci.us_balance = new

def stats(ci):
    print(ci.us_balance)

# Create an instance of the class
ci = Country()

while True:
    user_input = input("> ").lower()

    if user_input == "buy":
        amount = input("$ ").lower()
        balance_to_set = amount.split()
        buy(ci, balance_to_set[0], int(balance_to_set[1]))
    if user_input == "stats":
        stats(ci)
        break
```

Comment: apparently it was just because I forgot to call the .upper() function. It all works now! So no need to create and instance the class, my mistake was just kinda stupid

Comment: I don't understand, doesn't the value of us_balance in the stats remain 42 with only that function call change?

Comment: it only remained 42 because when I set "us" to lower in the class, I forgot to add the parenthesis, so python interpreted the comparison as false

Comment: Interesting, I just tried on repl.it and it works but on my local system (Python 3.7.2) it doesn't work unless I create a class instance.